add active class to navbar item link inside "li" when clicked (hash id url )
i have a single page application , most of sections inside index page (except login page ) ,
how to add active class to navbar item link "li" when clicked and match the correct URL path with hash id , for example  URL is "/#services". on my 'li' link item .
i am using nextjs ver 15 .
    <ul className="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
      <li className="nav-item">
        <Link
          className="nav-link  p-lg-3 p-4 "

          href="/"
        >
          Home
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li className="nav-item">
        

      <Link 
        className="nav-link  p-lg-3 p-4 "
      
      href="/#product"> 
        Products
      </Link>

      </li>
      <li className="nav-item">
        <Link
        
        className={`${router.asPath == "/#services" ? "active" : ""} nav-link p-lg-3 p-4`}
        href="/#services"
       
        >
          Services
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li className="nav-item">
        <Link className="nav-link p-lg-3 p-4" href="/#about_us" >
          About us
        </Link>
      </li>

      
      <li className="nav-item">
        <Link className="nav-link p-lg-3 p-4" href="/#">
          Support
          
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li className="nav-item">
        <Link className="nav-link p-lg-3 p-4" href="/account/login">
          Login
        </Link>
      </li>
    </ul>

i have tried :
   className={`${router.asPath == "/#services" ? "active" : ""} nav-link p-lg-3 p-4`}

but not worked .

thank you all , after many searching i found the solution , and not only when  click on the link will add class "active" , even when i scroll to the section will add the "active" class automatically to the navbar link . and here is my solution :
first :
1- add class to the "a" item inside 'li' as the same name of #id_link (same section id also ) , for example , the jsx in my navbar is :
  <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg background-color sticky-top">
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="/Images/company.png" alt="" />
      </a>
      <button
        className="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-bs-toggle="collapse"
        data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
      >
        <i className="fa-solid fa-bars-staggered" />
      </button>
      <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary ps-4 pe-4">
          Contact Us
        </button>
        <div className="Eng p-2 d-none d-lg-block">
          <i className="fa-solid fa-globe" />
          <span>English</span>
        </div>

        <ul className="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li className="nav-item">
            <Link
              className="nav-link  p-lg-3 p-4 "

              href="/"
            >
              Home
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item ">
            

          <Link 
            className="nav-link  p-lg-3 p-4 product "
          
          href="/#product"> 
            Products
          </Link>

          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <Link
            className="nav-link  p-lg-3 p-4 services "

            href="/#services"
           
            >
              Services
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <Link className="nav-link p-lg-3 p-4 about_us" href="/#about_us" >
              About us
            </Link>
          </li>

          
          <li className="nav-item">
            <Link className="nav-link p-lg-3 p-4" href="/#">
              Support
              
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <Link className="nav-link p-lg-3 p-4" href="/account/login">
              Login
            </Link>
          </li>
        </ul>


      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

2- create new html  section elements (which include all child elements ) and give it the target id , for example this is just 1 section :
  <section id="services"> 

  <div className="pack">
    <div className="serv background-image" />
    <div className="container-fluid d-flex align-items-center justify-content-evenly flex-lg-row flex-column">
      <div className="ft d-flex flex-column justify-content-evenly text-center justify-content-lg-center">
        <h2>Our Services</h2>
        <p> the Best in the markets</p>
      </div>
      <div className="text-11  ">
        <h3>
          We are committed to give the perfect scenarios of the following:
        </h3>
        <ul className="list-1">
          <li>Surveillance Systems</li>
          <li>Monitoring Systems</li>
          <li>Storage Solutions</li>
          <li>Asymmetric &amp; Symmetric DSL</li>
          <li>Fiber Connections</li>
          <li>Microwave Link installation</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  </section> 

3- inside navbar component use useEffect and add the following js code :
const pathname = usePathname() // remount the component if path changed
useEffect( () => {

  const sections = document.querySelectorAll("section");
  const navLi_a = document.querySelectorAll("nav .container-fluid .navbar-collapse ul li a ");    
  window.onscroll = () => {
    var current = "";
    sections.forEach((section) => {
      const sectionTop = section.offsetTop;
      if (scrollY  >= sectionTop - 60) {
        current = section.getAttribute("id"); }
    });
  
    navLi_a.forEach((a) => {
      a.classList.remove("active_nav_link");
      if (a.classList.contains(current)) {  
          a.classList.add("active_nav_link");
        }
    });
  };

},[pathname] )  

4- my css for active_nav_link class:
:root{
    --main-font-color: #58B3C8;
}


.active_nav_link {
    color: var(--main-font-color) !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--main-font-color); 
   
}

5- done.
